# Top Border Style Not Removing From Div in Bootsrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Can you please take a look at my code and website and let me know why the div's top border still remain despite of the fact that I set the the div border style to none and then to 0px width.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="well well-large  zerobox clearfix">
      <div class="zerobox margo pull-left">
          <img class="img-polaroid" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/260x120">
      </div>
      <div class="well well-large zerobox margo bordernone pull-right">
           <h4 class="text-error">Why The Top Border Still Here</h4>
                <br />
                <p>Test</p>
               <p>Test</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

and my custom style is :

```
<style>
.zerobox{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.margo{ margin: 10px 15px 10px 10px;}
.bordernone{border: solid 0px #F5F5F5;}
</style>
```

Here is the [Link](http://www.tehranmotor.ir/) to my web site.Please look at the top of "**Why The Top Border Still Here**" you can find a gray line at there.

Comment: Please check my answer... It shoudl resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not border. That is `box-shadow inset` from the bootstrap `.Well` class on your div. You need to reset that in your bordernone class.

Give this to your bordernone class <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aGdLQ/)</kbd>

```
-webkit-box-shadow: initial ;
-moz-box-shadow: initial ;
box-shadow: initial ;
```

This is the bootstrap css class that is applied.

```
.well {
min-height: 20px;
padding: 19px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```